# Change longitude from -180 to 180 to 0 to 360

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I want to change my longitude from -180 degrees to 180 deg format to 0-360 for an array. Is there a way to do this with out using loops or if statements?

```
lon_04_window = [ 1.39698386e-09   6.53551058e-02   1.30710210e-01   1.96065315e-01 2.61420419e-01   3.26775523e-01   3.92130628e-01   4.57485732e-01 5.22840836e-01   5.88195941e-01   6.53551045e-01   7.18906150e-01 7.84261254e-01   8.49616358e-01   9.14971463e-01   9.80326567e-01 1.04568167e+00   1.11103678e+00   1.17639188e+00   1.24174698e+00 1.30710209e+00   1.37245719e+00   1.43781230e+00   1.50316740e+00 1.56852251e+00   1.63387761e+00   1.69923272e+00   1.76458782e+00 1.82994292e+00   1.89529803e+00   1.96065313e+00   2.02600824e+00 2.09136334e+00   2.15671845e+00   2.22207355e+00   2.28742865e+00 2.35278376e+00   2.41813886e+00   2.48349397e+00   2.54884907e+00 2.61420418e+00   2.67955928e+00   2.74491439e+00   2.81026949e+00]
```

Loop Code:

```
for i in range(len(lon)):
    if lon[i] < 0:
        lon[i] = lon[i]+360
```

Comment: No, because even if you use any function for that, the function itself must use a loop. It can be done without if but definitely not without a loop.

Comment: Also what have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: How do you hope to iterate over the list without an iterator?

Comment: @cramopy the point is that I can write the code fine with a loop or if statement, but I am looking for a faster way.

Comment: @Rose but in your question you are asking for a `way without loop and if`, not for a faster way than you currently do. Then please edit your question and add your code you currently have.

Comment: If your longitude data is in a Numpy array then there _is_ an efficient way to do this without an explicit loop, thanks to the way the modulus operation works in Python & Numpy. Eg `lon_04_window %= 360.0`. However the data shown above is all small positive numbers, so I don't see how it's relevant to your question.

Comment: @PM2Ring The data I posted for longitude is just a small part of a 6,000 value data set

Comment: @Rose please then look at the source code of the functions you now use (or the functions given in the answer) -- those will definitlely use a Loop somewhere in code. this wont work witout a Loop -- that was what I stated.

Comment: @cramopy It is true that internally `numpy` is looping over array elements. However it is done in C and is significantly more efficient than the Python loop that @Roze provided as an example. We call it vectorized computations.

Comment: @AGNGazer I totally understand what this means -- and i accept that :) but the point is/was, that OP initially wanted a way without loop, and this is what i responded to. first then OP changed question to ask for *faster* method.

Comment: @cramopy Not using a for loop and if statement is a faster and more efficient method.

Comment: @cramopy Well, it is possible that the question could have been formulated more "accurately" but it is one of the better formulations that you will often find on SE. It was understandable (at least for me).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming `lon_04_window` is a numpy array AND that you want to go from [0,360] to [-180,180]:

```
((lon_04_window - 180) % 360) - 180
```

or

```
np.mod(lon_04_window - 180.0, 360.0) - 180.0
```

If you actually want to go from [-180,180] range to [0, 360] as stated in the OP:

```
lon_04_window % 360
```

If `lon_04_window` is not a `numpy` array, make it:

```
import numpy as np
lon_04_window = np.asarray(lon_04_window)
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.mod(lon_04_window, 360)` works fine as well.

Comment: As a side note `lon_04_window = (lon_04_window + 180) % 360` produces incorrect longitudes.

Comment: @Rich It is an answer to my question of how to convert lat from -180/180 to 0/360 without a loop. I should know, I asked the question. Also, two of the suggestions in the answer above don't actually work for my question.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def rewrap(x):
    return (x + 180) % 360 - 180
```

This can also be applied directly to NumPy arrays, not just scalars.

Answer (score -2):

In PostgresSQL:

```
UPDATE table SET lon = lon -360 WHERE lon > 180 ;
```

If the 0 begins in Greenwich.